# Javascript JSON output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, node.js

If have the following data which I fetch from my NodeJS app and I want to show via javascript.

```
{
    "holes": [{
        "par": 5,
        "strokeindex": 5
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 15
    }, {
        "par": 3,
        "strokeindex": 11
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 13
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "storkeindex": 1
    }, {
        "par": 3,
        "strokeindex": 17
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 9
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 7
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 3
    }, {
        "par": 5,
        "strokeindex": 6
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 16
    }, {
        "par": 3,
        "strokeindex": 13
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 14
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "storkeindex": 2
    }, {
        "par": 3,
        "strokeindex": 18
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 10
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 8
    }, {
        "par": 4,
        "strokeindex": 4
    }]
}
```

The data above is taken form the console where I have logged it with the following command:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Now I want to output all the "par" information from each object in data.holes to a variable to show on my page. I have tried it in many ways like:

```
var html = "";
for(i = 1; i < 18; i++) { 
    html += data.holes[1].par + '<br/>';
}
```

And like this:

```
var html = "";
for(i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
    html += JSON.stringify(data.holes[1].par) + '<br/>';
}
```

And like this:

```
var html = "";
for(i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
    html += JSON.parse(data.holes[1].par) + '<br/>';
}
```

But when I do it this way I will get errors like 'Cannot read property "par" of undefined' or 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o '. Does somebody know what's wrong?

Comment: no where are you declaring the i variable in the loop, also don't hardcode the `i < 18` as there may be more or less.  use `data.holes.length`

Comment: @musefan you can indeed do it with strings.

Comment: @Johan: Yep, just checked (i'll delete to avoid confusing the OP)

Comment: Is ajax involved?  If so, try confining your use of the data to the success callback.

Comment: This code looks like it runs fine (not including the `1` instead of `i`). Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates your error? I suspect it could be elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
for (var i = 1; i < data.holes.length; i++) {
   html += data.holes[i].par + '<br/>';
}
```

works for me
check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acP3d/1/)